# PyQt5 Change BackgroundRole Settings in QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using a QTableView in PyQT5 to display a table of data.

I can set the background colour of each cell based on a condition. For example to turn the cell red:

```
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):

        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if condition == ...
                return QtGui.QColor('#9C0006')
```

However instead of applying the background colour to the whole cell, I want to apply the colour to only part of the cell (based on the cell's value). For example like this:

[image]

Is this possible with QT, and if so, what settings would I need to change? I believe `QBrush` allows me set the fill pattern (i.e. a gradient like the image above), however is there class which handles the **size** of the background colour 'item' relative to the size of the cell, and it's placement within the cell?

**UPDATE:**

I now have the following code in Python, which sets the length of the gradient equal to 50% of cell width (which I can later set dynamically).

```
if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
    percent = 0.5

    gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(1, 0))
    gradient.setColorAt(0, Qt.red)
    gradient.setColorAt(percent, Qt.white)
    gradient.setColorAt(1, Qt.white)
    gradient.setCoordinateMode(QtGui.QLinearGradient.ObjectMode)


    return QtGui.QBrush(gradient)
```

This provides the following formatting:

[image]

Is there a way to provide a padding of say 5% to the top and bottom of each cells, so that the gradient formatting only fills 90% of the cell's vertical space rather than 100% currently? I.e. something like these (see top 3 rows).

[image]

I imagine I need to set the QBrush cooridinates so that the QBrush operation only takes place on part of the cell? However I can't seem to find anything within the QBrush documentation related to coordinates. Is this possible?

Comment: That kind of behavior can only been achieved through an item delegate, and by overriding its [`paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) method. If you've already tried that, provide us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise do some research about that and then edit your question by providing the aforementioned MRE in case you still need some help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go.

Comment: @musicamante, Use an item delegate is not an obligation. You can achieve this behavior with `QBrush` and a `QLinearGradient` in `Qt::BackgroundRole`

Comment: @thibsc Yes, you're completely right. I'm afraid I've got so used to delegates (and so tired too...) that I didn't thought about the simplest solution.

Comment: What you ask in the edit is a completely different matter: full item painting depends on the style, so in this case a delegate is probably required (or, at least, using a QStyleProxy); I'd suggest you to create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is possible by using `QBrush` with a `QGradient`, I give you an example with Qt C++, just adapt to python:

> [`QBrush::QBrush(const QGradient &gradient)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#QBrush-9)
>   [`QLinearGradient`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineargradient.html)

```cpp
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override {
    QVariant ret;
    if (index.isValid()){
        if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole){
            bool convert = false;
            double percent = index.data().toDouble(&convert);
            if (convert){
                QColor c = (percent < 25 ? Qt::red
                             : (percent < 50 ? Qt::yellow
                                 : (percent < 75 ? Qt::green : Qt::cyan)));
                QLinearGradient grad(QPointF(0, 0), QPointF(1, 0));
                grad.setCoordinateMode(QGradient::CoordinateMode::ObjectBoundingMode);
                grad.setColorAt(0, c);
                grad.setColorAt(percent/100.0, Qt::white);
                grad.setColorAt(1, Qt::white);

                ret = QBrush(grad);
            }
        } else {
            ret = QAbstractTableModel::data(index, role);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

---

**Result**: You will have something like this:
[image: result]

Comment: I'd suggest a small modification: using `Qt::white` won't always be a good thing, especially if the current style uses a different `Base` palette color, or if the item view's background uses a custom stylesheet or palette: `Qt::transparent` would probably be more consistent. I'd also adapt your answer to actual python code, since the question uses that language, but I'm usually not comfortable in editing answers; if you're ok with that and can't/won't do it on your own, just tell me that.

Comment: @musicamante, Yes if course `Qt::transparent` is better. It's juste a simple example and if you want to edit for python I'm okay but I think that the answer is helpful even in C++ because it is not difficult to translate this code in python ;)

Comment: @thibsc yes very helpful even in C++, it gives me the general idea which I can adapt to python :)