# Pyqt5 Applying part colour to cells of columns of a table based on cell's percentage value

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have used the info form this post: [PyQt5 Change BackgroundRole Settings in QAbstractTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648473/pyqt5-change-backgroundrole-settings-in-qabstracttablemodel) and have the following python script, but I don't know why the gradient is only being applied for column 0.  Could someone please offer the solution to get columns 1 and 2 to also show their respective gradients?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._data[0]) if self.rowCount() > 0 else 0

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            row = index.row()
            col = index.column()
            if 0 <= row < self.rowCount() and 0 <= col < self.columnCount():
                percent = self._data[row][col]
                gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(1, 0))

                # Adjust gradient stop positions for each column
                if col == 0:
                    gradient.setColorAt(0, Qt.red)
                    gradient.setColorAt(percent, Qt.white)
                elif col == 1:
                    gradient.setColorAt(1, Qt.blue)  # Reverse direction: Start from (1, 0) to (0, 0)
                    gradient.setColorAt(1 - percent, Qt.white)
                elif col == 2:
                    gradient.setColorAt(0, Qt.green)
                    gradient.setColorAt(percent, Qt.white)

                gradient.setCoordinateMode(QtGui.QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
                return QtGui.QBrush(gradient)
        elif role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            col = index.column()
            if 0 <= row < self.rowCount() and 0 <= col < self.columnCount():
                percent = self._data[row][col]
                return '{:.0%}'.format(percent)  # Format as percentage text

        return QtCore.QVariant()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = [
        [0.4, 0.5, 0.8],
        [0.3, 0.6, 0.9],
        [0.9, 0.7, 1.0],
        [0.9, 0.7, 1.0]
    ]
    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
    table = QTableView(widget)
    model = TableModel(data)
    table.setModel(model)
    layout.addWidget(table)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug.

The default behavior of QCommonStyle (on which any standard style relies for drawing the "panel" of a view item) just calls the QPainter [`setBrushOrigin()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setBrushOrigin), but doesn't consider that gradients using `ObjectBoundingMode` rely on the absolute origin of the object to draw the contents, so the gradient is actually *shifted*.

That can be easily confirmed by resizing the columns, which shows that the gradient is actually drawn, but shifted by the section position; add the following lines right before returning the brush in `data()`:

```py
                gradient.setColorAt(0.01, gradient.stops()[0][1])
                gradient.setColorAt(0, Qt.black)
```

If you then resize the second column, you will see that the black region is exactly as wide as the first column, and if you also resize the first column that same region becomes resized as well.

Second column resized, showing the black region and the rest of the gradient:

[image: Second column showing the black region]

First column resized, showing that the black region of the second column is as wide as the first, with the gradient shifted accordingly:

[image: First column resized showing the similar width]

A possible work around is to use a custom item delegate, check whether the background brush has a gradient, and eventually set a translated transform on the brush, which will "invert" the result of `setBrushOrigin()`:

```py
class GradientDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        if opt.backgroundBrush.gradient() is not None:
            opt.backgroundBrush.setTransform(
                QTransform().translate(-opt.rect.x(), -opt.rect.y()))

...

table.setItemDelegate(GradientDelegate(table))
```

The above also works for non horizontal linear gradients, and any other gradient type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks musicamante, works brilliantly.  Can I ask is there a way to achieve this but abruptly stopping the color at a percentage (as opposed to fading the color)?

Comment: @Kankan2000 If you want clearly defined colors, then there's absolutely no point in using gradients at all. Create a custom delegate, change the `Qt.BackgroundRole` result of `data()` to return the reference color, and in the [`paint()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) override of the delegate use the painter `fillRect()` with an adjusted rectangle based on the `option.rect` and the index data (use a custom user role for the `percent` value) for its width, then just call the default `super().paint(...)` to draw the rest. If you don't understand the above, post a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted a question related to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741176/pyqt5-partially-coloring-in-cells-of-a-table-by-its-value

Comment: After researching, I have posted a couple of issues I have encountered related to implementing a solid color effect here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77742085/pyqt5-change-progress-bar-backround-of-cells-to-transparent-and-adjust-text-prop