# PyQt5 Change progress bar backround of Cells to transparent and adjust text properties

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a table with cells that have percentage values and the corresponding progress bar updating every 2 seconds.  I don't know if it is the most efficient way to do it, but it seems to be working ok.  But I am trying to get the background of the cells transparent (at the moment it is a light grey) and I want to align the text to the right and vertically central) and be able to set the text colour.  The code is below but the section that changes the text and background isn't working.  If someone could explain the issue that would be great thanks.

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from table_layout import TableExample
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import random

def generate_data(rows, columns):
    data = []
    for _ in range(rows):
        row = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(columns)]
        data.append(row)
    return data

def update_data():
    global ex  # Access the TableExample instance
    rows = 50
    columns = 6
    new_data = generate_data(rows, columns)
    ex.updateTable(new_data)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Generate initial data
    rows = 50
    columns = 6
    generated_data = generate_data(rows, columns)
    # Specify colors for each column
    column_colors = [
        QColor(255, 0, 0),  # Red
        QColor(0, 255, 0),  # Green
        QColor(0, 0, 255),  # Blue
        QColor(255, 255, 0),  # Yellow
        QColor(255, 0, 255),  # Magenta
        QColor(0, 255, 255),  # Cyan
    ]

    global ex  # Make ex accessible from update_data function
    ex = TableExample(generated_data, column_colors)
    # Set up QTimer to update data every 2 seconds
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(update_data)
    timer.start(2000)  # 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

table_layout

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class TableExample(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data, column_colors):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.column_colors = column_colors
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bars')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        rows = len(self.data)
        columns = len(self.data[0])

        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)  # Set the table as central widget

        self.table.setRowCount(rows)
        self.table.setColumnCount(columns)

        # Set column titles
        column_titles = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX"]
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(column_titles)

        for col in range(columns):
            color = self.column_colors[col]
            for row in range(rows):
                progress = QProgressBar()
                value = self.data[row][col]
                progress.setValue(value)

                style = f"QProgressBar::chunk {{background-color: {color.name()};}}"
                progress.setStyleSheet(style)

                #####below isn't aligning text and changing background colour of cells to transparent)
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)  # Align text to the right and center vertically
                item.setForeground(QColor("blue"))  # Set text color to blue
                item.setBackground(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))  # Set transparent background
                self.table.setItem(row, col, item)  # Set the QTableWidgetItem
                item.setText(str(value))

                self.table.setCellWidget(row, col, progress)

        self.show()

    def updateTable(self, new_data):
        rows = len(new_data)
        columns = len(new_data[0])

        for col in range(columns):
            for row in range(rows):
                new_value = new_data[row][col]

                # Update QTableWidgetItem
                item = self.table.item(row, col)
                item.setText(str(new_value))

                # Update QProgressBar
                progress = self.table.cellWidget(row, col)
                progress.setValue(new_value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text and color is properly set, but it's not visible because the progress bar occupies the whole cell (the gray you see is the background of the progress bar), and cell widgets are stacked *on top* of item cells, so you should theoretically make the progress bar background transparent in the stylesheet:

```py
style = f'''
    QProgressBar {{
        background: transparent;
    }}
    QProgressBar::chunk {{
        background: {color.name()};
    }}
'''
```

This won't be acceptable, though: the value would be shown twice (the item and the progress bar), and even if you hide the progress bar text (by calling [`QProgressBar.setFormat()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#format-prop) with an empty string), the filled region will eventually cover the item text as soon as the value is closer to 100.

In general, using widgets for such a purpose is discouraged, and proper item delegates should be used instead. Not only they require much less resources (you don't need a widget for each cell), but they make value updates much more direct and consistent.

To achieve this, the value should be set as a number (not a string), and a custom user role must be used in order to show different progress bar colors.

```py
ProgressColorRole = Qt.UserRole + 1

class ProgressDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, qp, opt, index):
        progress = index.data()
        if isinstance(progress, (int, float)):
            color = index.data(ProgressColorRole)
            if not isinstance(color, QColor) or not color.isValid():
                color = QApplication.palette().highlight()
            rect = QRectF(opt.rect)
            rect.setWidth(rect.width() * progress / 100)
            qp.save()
            qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
            qp.setBrush(color)
            qp.drawRect(rect)
            qp.restore()
        super().paint(qp, opt, index)


class TableExample(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bars')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.table.setItemDelegate(ProgressDelegate(self.table))

        self.updateTable(self.data)

    def updateTable(self, data):
        self.table.setRowCount(len(data))
        self.table.setColumnCount(len(data[0]))

        column_titles = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX"]
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(column_titles)

        for row, rowData in enumerate(data):
            for col, value in enumerate(rowData):
                item = self.table.item(row, col)
                if item is None:
                    item = QTableWidgetItem()
                    item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
                    item.setForeground(Qt.blue) 
                    item.setData(ProgressColorRole, self.column_colors[col])
                    self.table.setItem(row, col, item)

                item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, value)
```

I strongly recommend you to carefully read through the [Qt Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) documentation, and look for resources about delegates, including posts here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the correct working solution, detailed information and suggestion, I really appreciate it :)